# Will multiple push notifications opt-ins be an issue with iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Quick question, if I develop an app and create a dedicated "alerts screen" and on that screen will be a list of 200 teams, next to each team will be "news" and "transfers".

So the user has the option to opt in to push notifications for only the teams they choose but also narrow down to just news or transfers for example.

Will this be an issue with iOS? I know Parse and others allow "segmentation and channelling" but I am not sure if this is the best way as my app has no user login/registration, I will be doing it via device token.

Comment: You can easily use UUID and KeyChain for your purpose to track the settings for help see this http://iosameer.blogspot.in/2012/08/alternative-to-ios-device-uuid.html

Answer (score 0):

It won't be an issue with iOS, as long as you plan to support this functionality in your server - once the user chooses the types of notifications they prefer to see, you'll send these types along with the device token to your server and store them in your DB. Your server will send push notifications to each device token based on those preferences.

That being said, a UI screen with 200 options to choose from doesn't seem very user friendly. You should think how to make it less painful for the user to make those choices.